# Remove part of a string using KornShell

Tags: shell, variables, scripting, ksh

I have this string DFUB1AG.T1310LC.C140206.XIYG000.FCIPHE31 and I need to remove the first part of it. How can I do this?

As has been asked here is what I want to achieve.

Want to get this string that is separated by "."

```
DFUB1AG.T1310LC.C140206.XIYG000.FCIPHE31
```

And want to remove the first part of it to get the result as below

```
T1310LC.C140206.XIYG000.FCIPHE31
```

I have already achieved it by doing this way:

Okay guys I got it done by doing this.

```
# var=DFUB1AG.T1310LC.C140206.XIYG000.FCIPHE31
# var=${var#*.}
# echo $var
# T1310LC.C140206.XIYG000.FCIPHE31
```

Comment: please edit your question to define your expected output. What are you using to define parts in that string `1`, or `T13` or just `'.'`? AND as stackoverflow is about helping with coding problems, include what you ave tried so far. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If STRING is your variable, and you want to strip everything before first dot you can say STRING=${STRING#*.} ........Removes shortest match at beginning of string of any character followed by a dot.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$VarWithYourString" | sed "s/^[^.]\{1,\}./"
```

or

```
sed "s/^[^.]\{1,\}./" YourFileInput
```